# Access SQL: syntax error(missing operator)

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax-error

My task is: *Choose all profitable flights*.
`transportation` is a general information about the flight.`ticket` includes information about a number of tickets and their cost.
So I tried to update column `profit` after that find the most profitable
but I gained such an error
[syntax error(missing operator)in query expression'((tt.cost*(tt.sold_q+tt.booked_q))-(0,2* trans.plan_oil))
FROM transportation trans'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuIN2.png)

```
UPDATE transportation
set profit =((tt.cost*(tt.sold_q+tt.booked_q))-(0,2* trans.plan_oil))
FROM transportation trans, transportation.ticket tt
WHERE profit is null

union

SELECT TOP 1
FROM transposition trans
WHERE profit>0
```

I'm a newbie, so I  will be glad for any help

Comment: The [syntax of UPDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845036.aspx) is : `UPDATE table SET newvalue WHERE criteria;`, there is no such thing like `UPDATE .... UNION SELECT ...`, so you have got syntax error because MS-Access doesn't understand this command. Please explain what exctly do you want to do.

Comment: Also, in SQL view you need the US number format: `0.2` instead of `0,2`

Comment: I removed the part with a union and changed `0,2` to `0.2` but the problem stays the same. I want to set value `profit`((ticket cost*(all amount of tickets))-(oil which was spent*0.2)) for each empty row in the table `transportations`. After that, I want to get only rows with `profit` value larger than 0 and show it

Comment: There is no `FROM` clause in update queries of Access SQL dialect.

Comment: Even if you fix the SQL syntax, the query won't work because union queries are not updateable.

Comment: thx, now `UPDATE` part works but how am I supposed to find only  that rows with profit greater than 0, if I shouldn't use `union`. Working part: `UPDATE transportations
set profit =((transportations.ticket.cost*(transportations.ticket.sold_q+transportations.ticket.booked_q))-(0.2* transportations.plan_oil))
WHERE profit is null`

Comment: Change your WHERE clause into `WHERE profit >0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UPDATE and SELECT table concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51011712/update-and-select-table-concatenation)