# UPDATE and SELECT table concatenation

Tags: mysql, ms-access, concatenation

My task is: Choose all profitable flights. `transportation` is a general information about the flight. `ticket` includes information about a number of tickets and their cost. So, how to concatenate `UPDATE` and `SELECT` table in order to find only those rows with `profit` greater than 0.`UPDATE` table should go first because `profit` field is empty

```
UPDATE transportations
set profit =((transportations.ticket.cost* 
(transportations.ticket.sold_q+transportations.ticket.booked_q))-(0.2* 
transportations.plan_oil))
WHERE profit is null

SELECT profit FROM transportations
WHERE profit >0
ORDER BY profit
```

Comment: What is wrong about executing two separate queries?

Comment: Currently, it's unclear what you're asking.  If `Profit` is calculated, you probably shouldn't store it at all

Answer (score 0):

Saving calculated data is usually not advisable. And you appear to be using a multi-value field. How can you save each ticket profit calc? Saving profit for each flight record would require aggregating the ticket calcs. Saving aggregate data with an UPDATE will result in a 'non-updatable' error.

If you want to return each ticket's profit calc and only those greater than 0, try:

```
SELECT *, (ticket.cost * (ticket.sold_q + ticket.booked_q))-(0.2* plan_oil) AS Profit
FROM transportations
WHERE (ticket.cost * (ticket.sold_q + ticket.booked_q))-(0.2* plan_oil) > 0;
```

If you want to consider the aggregate profit for each flight, try:

```
SELECT FlightID, Sum((ticket.cost * (ticket.sold_q + ticket.booked_q))-(0.2* plan_oil)) AS Profit
FROM transportations
GROUP BY FlightID
HAVING Sum((ticket.cost * (ticket.sold_q + ticket.booked_q))-(0.2* plan_oil)) > 0;
```